# Angular Material tabs do not carry over data attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using [Angular Material tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs) (`<md-tabs>`). When adding a `data` attribute such as `data-filter` on the tab element, the built in Material directive does not bring it over when it converts them.

For example, this is my markup:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
      <md-tab label="one" data-filter="tab-one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <p>Tab 1</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two" data-filter="tab-two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <p>Tab 2</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

And this is the markup of just `tab-one` after Angular Material has rendered it:

```
<md-tab-item tabindex="-1" class="md-tab ng-scope ng-isolate-scope md-ink-ripple md-active" style="max-width: 1280px" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false" ng-click="$mdTabsCtrl.select(tab.getIndex())" ng-class="{'md-active': tab.isActive(), 'md-focused': tab.hasFocus(), 'md-disabled': tab.scope.disabled }" ng-disabled="tab.scope.disabled" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.nextPage()" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.previousPage()" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent">
  <span class="ng-scope">one</span>
  <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
</md-tab-item>
```

As you can see from above, it does not have the `data-filter="tab-one"` within it. Is there a way of modifying or hooking into the directive to pull all data attributes over?

[**Working Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWawZL)

**EDIT:** Did further testing, and it also does not bring over IDs or classes.

Comment: So from workaround point of view , what do you plan to do with these attributes?

Comment: Just binding them to an event. So for any elements of `md-tab-item` with a data attr of `filter`, the click event will be bound to them.

Comment: Might just have to try a work around and use the `md-on-select` with a function. Such as `<md-tab md-on-select="filter('tab-one')">`

Comment: always simpler to use built in api approach before creating your own anyway

Comment: I agree. Do you happen to have any suggestions @charlietfl?

Comment: yes...was referring to `md-on-select` like you showed